# compare data in excel to access data if different show cell in red

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access

I have excel pulling a query from an access database to display data based on some criteria however I have another sheet which users can input data in for the week and that is pushed into access via VBA when the user clicks on a button with a macro assigned to it.

I believe my suedo code should be something like this.

```
load data from access onto sheet2
compare  sheet1 data to sheet2 if different show cell in red.
on update only enter sheet1 data if different to sheet2
```

I have the access database set up already and the spreadsheet set up however I am trying to fine tune this so that I can roll it out to my team in work so they can manage their own work time and update it into the access database for a log and to produce reports on this.

Hope this is clear enough

(my current insert into access code in vba looks like this)

```html
    Option Explicit
    Const TARGET_DB = "kpistats.accdb"

    Sub PushkpidataToAccess()
        Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
        Dim MyConn
        Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
        Dim i As Long, j As Long
        Dim Rw As Long
        
        Sheets("data").Activate
        Rw = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

        Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
        MyConn = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & TARGET_DB
        
        With cnn
            .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
            .Open MyConn
        End With

        Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
        rst.CursorLocation = adUseServer
        rst.Open Source:="data", ActiveConnection:=cnn, _
                 CursorType:=adOpenDynamic, LockType:=adLockOptimistic, _
                 Options:=adCmdTable
        
        'Load all records from Excel to Access.
        For i = 2 To Rw
            rst.AddNew
            For j = 1 To 8
                rst(Cells(1, j).Value) = Cells(i, j).Value
            Next j
            rst.Update
        Next i
        
        ' Close the connection
        rst.Close
        cnn.Close
        Set rst = Nothing
        Set cnn = Nothing

    End Sub
```

Many Thanks

Simon

Comment: Can you give the users an Access form to input data for the week?

Comment: you could highlight invalid data using [Conditional Formatting using a formula](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f)

Comment: The reason im not using access forms is each person (up to 20) will have their own spreadsheet Or would using access forms be better in this instance?

Comment: Suppose you add a *user_id* field to your Access table.  Then create a single Access form (not 20 forms), which presents the user only those rows associated with his or her *user_id*.  And when the user adds a new record, the correct *user_id* is automatically included.  Would you then have any remaining need for 20 Excel worksheets?  If not, I believe an Access form solution should be much simpler than the Excel approach you described.  OTOH, if you're proficient with Excel but not Access, perhaps the Access solution is not right for you.

Comment: On the other, other hand, @HansUp, Access & Excel VBA are close enough that it's not hard to learn one if you know the other. I agree with your assessment of doing it all in Access. The biggest drawback is that Access, despite all Microsoft's claims otherwise, really sucks with 20 concurrent users (more than 10 is getting sketchy). There are ways around that, though, many of them documented here at SO, and other places around the web.

Answer (score 0):

If the approach is to check each row to see if it's duplicated in Sheet2, then insert a record if it isn't, what I'd suggest is to have it add a new column in sheet 1 (say column I) , add a 'Check If Match' TRUE/FALSE field, then add a condition in your For loop to only insert if it's not matching.

```
    Option Explicit
    Const TARGET_DB = "kpistats.accdb"

    Sub PushkpidataToAccess()
        Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
        Dim MyConn
        Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
        Dim i As Long, j As Long
        Dim Rw As Long

        Sheets("data").Activate
        Rw = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

        Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
        MyConn = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & TARGET_DB

        With cnn
            .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
            .Open MyConn
        End With

        Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
        rst.CursorLocation = adUseServer
        rst.Open Source:="data", ActiveConnection:=cnn, _
                 CursorType:=adOpenDynamic, LockType:=adLockOptimistic, _
                 Options:=adCmdTable

        'Add the Match field to column i 
        Range("I2:I" & rw).Formula = "=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A2,Sheet2!A:A,FALSE)),FALSE,TRUE)"

        'Load all records from Excel to Access.
        For i = 2 To Rw
            If Cells(i, 9) = True Then
                rst.AddNew
                For j = 1 To 8
                    rst(Cells(1, j).Value) = Cells(i, j).Value
                Next j
                rst.Update

            End If
        Next i


        ' Close the connection
        rst.Close
        cnn.Close
        Set rst = Nothing
        Set cnn = Nothing

    End Sub
```

Another alternative may be easier, put a Unique constraint on the table you are inserting, then before you start inserting records do On Error Resume Next - Excel will fail to insert duplicates but keep trying until it reaches the last row.